# Alert box not working when input submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two numbers, 20 and 0.

My code is supposed to display an alert box based on either of two numbers entered and submitted. But nothing happens once I click submit when I enter either of the two numbers.

Not sure if form action attribute is the reason but it's a single page html document named compact.html, hence the value of the action attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Check PIN</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function userCode {

    if (document.registration.pincode.value == "20") {
        alert("Congrats, you passed!");
        document.registration.pincode.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (document.registration.pincode.value =="0") {
        alert("Sorry, you failed!");
        document.registration.pincode.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return (true);
   }    
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
 <form action="compact.html" name="registration" onsubmit = "return(userCode());">
    <label>Please enter your PIN:</label><br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="pincode"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo.  You forgot the parentheses when defining the `userCode` function.  Always check the browser's debugging console for errors, this would be showing up as a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks @David I missed that. But I fixed it and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use html's onclick event to fire the JS function; for that the following line needs to change :

```
 <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

with following:

```
 <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="userCode()">
```

Note: You can always debug your code on Browser console (By Pressing function key - f12)

Comment: Great! this is the solution. But is there any reason my solution wasn't working, would be glad to know.

Comment: yes one of the reason could be, no action event found for form-submit, also this is wrong syntax: onsubmit = "return(userCode());

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Thank you.

Comment: i executed your code on my locale, you can also use input type="submit" to make it happen with less changes with your code.

Comment: Yes! This is what i was missing. Thank you.